# MODX getResources displays child resources of unlisted resource

Tags: modx, modx-getresources

I have the following getResources code on a page:

```
[[!getResources? 
                &resources=`57,77`
                &depth=`1`
                &tpl=`customersListTPL` 
                &limit=`99`  
                &sortdir=`ASC`  
                &includeTVs=`1`  
                &processTVs=`1`
                &includeContent=`1`
                &showHidden=`1`
                &depth=`0`  
                &sortby=`menuindex`  
            ]]
```

I want it to only display data from the resources 57 and 77, but it is also displaying child resources from the resource this is on too.

Anyway I can stop that?

Comment: try adding `&parents=-1` (with backticks around the *-1*)

Comment: @Yoshi yep that did it! Want to make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some design-reason `getResources` will allways mix results from the defined parents (explicit or implicit) if the `&parents` config is not set.

If you only want to use the defined `&resources` you have to explicitly disable the parents by using:

```
&parents=`-1`
```

For reference: That's not the only oddity of `getResources`, the limit is preset to `5` and the sort order is `createdon=DESC` (for example).

---

Manual: https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources#getResources-Examples